# how a toplevel class can inherite from the main class tkinter opp inorder to access main class's attr

Tags: python, tkinter, inheritance, subclass, toplevel

I want to access the main window attributes and change some of its labels and button's states in my toplevel class however it can not find them. So I'm not sure how to use opp approach in tkinter and I tried using super__init__ and text variable but I failed. The main problem is inheritance in tkinter frame work and i highlighted it in def login 2. I appreciate the help. peace.

```
import tkinter as tk
import sqlite3
cnt = sqlite3.connect("simple_store.db")

class MainWindow():
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master=master
        self.master.geometry('350x200')
        self.master.resizable(False, False)

        self.lbl_msg = tk.Label(self.master, text='')
        self.lbl_msg.pack()

        self.login_btn = tk.Button(self.master, text="Login ", command=login)
        self.login_btn.pack()

        self.submit_btn = tk.Button(self.master, text="Submit", command=submit)
        self.submit_btn.pack()


class submit:
    pass

class login(MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):

        self.login_win = tk.Toplevel()
        self.login_win.title("Login")
        self.login_win.geometry("350x200")

        self.lbl_temp = tk.Label(self.login_win, text='')
        self.lbl_temp.pack()

        self.lbl_user = tk.Label(self.login_win, text='Username:')
        self.lbl_user.pack()

        self.userw = tk.Entry(self.login_win, width=15)
        self.userw.pack()

        self.lbl_pass = tk.Label(self.login_win, text='Password')
        self.lbl_pass.pack()

        self.passwordw = tk.Entry(self.login_win, width=15)
        self.passwordw.pack()

        self.login_btn2 = tk.Button(self.login_win, text="Login", command= self.login2)
        self.login_btn2.pack(pady=20)

        self.login_win.mainloop()

    def login2(self):
        global userid

        self.user = self.userw.get()
        self.password = self.passwordw.get()

        query = '''SELECT * FROM customers WHERE username=? AND PASSWORD=?'''
        result = cnt.execute(query, (self.user, self.password))
        row = result.fetchall()

        if (row):
            self.lbl_temp.configure(text="welcome")
            userid = row[0][0]

            ####the problem is here####

            self.lbl_msg.configure(text="welcome " + self.user)
            # self.login_btn.configure(state="disabled")


            self.userw.delete(0, 'end')
            self.passwordw.delete(0, 'end')
        else:
            self.lbl_temp.configure(text="error")



root = tk.Tk()
window = MainWindow(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You don't need this self.login_win.mainloop().

Comment: I would suggest you to go through some tutorials on Python OOP since you have a wrong understanding of inheritance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use inheritance for this. Inheritance is an "is a" relationship. If you inherit from `MainWindow` than your other window is a `MainWindow` with extra features. You don't want two `MainWindow` instances.

Instead, you need to pass the instance of `MainWindow` to `login`.

```
class MainWindow():
    def __init__(self,master):
        ...
        self.login_btn = tk.Button(self.master, text="Login ", command=self.login)
        ...

    def login(self):
        login_window = login(main_window=self)
        #                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

class login():
    def __init__(self, main_window):
        self.main_window = main_window
        ...

    def login2(self):
        ...
        self.main_window.lbl_msg.configure(text="welcome " + self.user)
        #    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
        ...
```

Comment: Based on your description, then why does `login` still inherit from `MainWindow`? Also the argument of `login.__init__()` is `main_window` but you use `main` in `login(main=self)`.

Comment: @acw1668: oops! That was a mistake. Thanks for bringing it to my attention.

Comment: It was a great help. please check out my new post and help me with it.

Answer (score 0):

Alright so, in order for you to inherit from the main class, you have to make your `__init__()` method's signature the same + whatever you might need for the top level class.

Example:

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, attr1):
        self.attr1 = attr1

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, attr1, attr2):
        super().__init__(attr1) # You can manipulate attr1 here
        self.attr2 = attr2
        # You can also manipulate attr1 here using
        # self.attr1 = whatever value.
```